# How to remove the grid on the cylinder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a script for plotting a cylinder using the function data_for_cylinder_along_z. How to remove the grid on the cylinder? Is it possible to set two colours for it?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D                         
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch

# Coordinate for the cylinder
def data_for_cylinder_along_z(center_x,center_y,radius,height_z):
    z = np.linspace(0, height_z, 200)
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 200)
    theta_grid, z_grid=np.meshgrid(theta, z)
    x_grid = radius*np.cos(theta_grid) + center_x
    y_grid = radius*np.sin(theta_grid) + center_y
    return x_grid,y_grid,z_grid

figsize=[5,5]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.azim = -65   
ax.elev = 11    

ax.set_xlim(0.03, 0.049)
ax.set_ylim(0.02, 0.04)
ax.set_zlim(0.009, 0.02)

y_shift = 0.1
# Cylinder
Xc,Zc,Yc = data_for_cylinder_along_z(0,0,0.05,0.14)      # center_x,center_y,radius,height_z
ax.plot_surface(Xc, Yc+y_shift, Zc, alpha=0.4, color = 'blue')

# Setting 
ax.get_proj = lambda: np.dot(Axes3D.get_proj(ax), np.diag([0.2, 1, 0.13, 1]))

# Hide axes
ax._axis3don = False

plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not of much help here but if you don't want grids for visual purposes, one thing you can try is to have a lot of grids so that it become indistinguishable.

`ax.plot_surface(Xc, Yc+y_shift, Zc, alpha=0.1,rstride=1, cstride=1, color = 'blue')`

I really did not get what you mean by `to set two colours` : Did you mean 1) have a separate color for outer surface and inner surface? or 2)have a gradient of 2 color ?

Comment: If it's first one, one improvised method that I can think of (again not the correct answer) is to superpose 2 cylinders, so inside would be grey and outside will be the result of superposition

`ax.plot_surface(Xc, Yc+y_shift, Zc, alpha=0.1,rstride=1, cstride=1, color = 'blue')
ax.plot_surface(Xc-0.0001, Yc+y_shift-0.0001, Zc-0.0001, alpha=0.1,rstride=1, cstride=1, color = 'red')` 

If it's the later,

`ax.plot_surface(Xc, Yc+y_shift, Zc, alpha=0.1,rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.bwr)` or something like that

Comment: Thank you very much. Decreasing of the alpha parameter has solved my problem. By 'colours' I mean something like the trick you have recommended.